# Embedding VLC player in WInform Application in .Net Core. Core.Intialize() Giving Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, libvlc

I am trying to Embed VLc in Winform Application on .net core 3.1 framework. Packages installed are
**
LibVLCSharp 3.6.1
LibVLCSharp.WinForms 3.6.1
**

```
private void PlayerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var url = typeof(LibVLC).Assembly.Location;
            Core.Initialize();
            using(var libvlc = new LibVLC())
                using (var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc))
            {
                var uri = new Uri("C:\\Active Projects\\ScreenPlayerWeb\\ScreenPlayerWeb\\wwwroot\\Videos\\VID_20190621_112556.3gp");
                using var media = new Media(libvlc, uri);
                mediaPlayer.Fullscreen = true;
                mediaPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
```

Core.Initialize() Giving Exception

**
LibVLCSharp.Shared.VLCException: 'Failed to load required native libraries.
Have you installed the latest LibVLC package from nuget for your target platform?
Search paths include C:\Active Projects\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libvlc\win-x64\libvlc.dll,C:\Active Projects\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libvlc\win-x64\libvlccore.dll; C:\Active Projects\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libvlc\win-x64\libvlc.dll,C:\Active Projects\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libvlc\win-x64\libvlccore.dll; C:\Active Projects\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\ScreenPlayerClient\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\libvlc.dll,'

**

Its searching for wrong file in my devug/netcore3.1 folder there is no file as libvlc.dll ...
files avaialble are libvlcsharp.dll, libvlcsharp.winforms.dll and vlc.dotnet.core.dll.

There are answers on stack overflow but most of these are more than 5 years old so cant be referenced to updated versions of LIbVlc and .Net

Help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: The exception message has the answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package doesn't include the actual 'libvlc' as you might expect, its only initialization code in the LibVLCSharp. Ensure you installed the `VideoLAN.LibVLC.[YourPlatform]` package in your target project. Or [download it manually](http://nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows) and point towards the folder:

```
Core.Initialize(@"C:\yourpath\libvlc\win-x64");
var libvlc = new LibVLC();
// Make VideoView control
VideoView vv = new VideoView();
vv.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
vv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
// Add it to the form
Controls.Add(vv);

var uri = new Uri(@"C:\Video.mp4");
// Use command line options as Options for media playback (https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)
var media = new Media(libvlc, uri, ":input-repeat=65535");
vv.MediaPlayer.Play(media);

//Set fullscreen
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is highly appriciated. If possible Guide me with few tricks. I want my Video on Repeat in player, I am playing this video in full screen but i am not able to kill that how to kill the player?

Comment: Direct me to any documentation page they have. Regards. Thanks.

Comment: Their [documentation page](https://videolan.videolan.me/vlc/group__libvlc.html) is not too usefull for C#. You should ask a new question according to stackoverflow rules. However I would suggest using the LibVLCWinForms `VideoView` to embedd VLC in your application. This will prevent using the `Fullscreen = true` option but you can just make your form borderless and size it to the screen yourself. As for repeat add Media option `":input-repeat=65535"`. Ill edit my answer, but dont downvote me for answering multiple questions.

Comment: Thank you very much @fixation. I wasnot aware of the rule. I will Take Care next time. Anyways Lots of Regards and Thanks.