# Embedding LIb.VLC in winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, libvlc

This Question is In reference with my previous question [Embedding VLC player in WInform Application in .Net Core. Core.Intialize() Giving Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593147/embedding-vlc-player-in-winform-application-in-net-core-core-intialize-givin?noredirect=1#comment123038693_69593147)

I want to run the player for certain time and during that time video should be on repeat. Currently code looks like this ...

```
Core.Initialize();
            var libvlc = new LibVLC();
            // Make VideoView control
            VideoView vv = new VideoView();
            vv.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libvlc);
            vv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            // Add it to the form
            Controls.Add(vv);

            var uri = new Uri(@"C:\vid.3gp");
            // Use command line options as Options for media playback (https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)
            var media = new Media(libvlc, uri, ":input-repeat=65535");
            vv.MediaPlayer.Play(media);

            //Set fullscreen
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
            this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;
```

How I can close the player after certain time. currently even if I close the form with the player video keeps playing in background till I close the whole application.

Just to inform the this winform application is created in .netcore3.1.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create MediaPlayer as class field and call it to start/pause/stop it in you WinForm application.

```
private LibVLC _libVlc;
private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
...

// Call this method in your constructor/initializer
private void StartMediaPlayer(string videoUrl)
{
    using var media = new Media(_libVlc, new Uri(videoUrl), ":input-repeat=65535");
    _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVlc)
    {
        Media = media
    };

    _mediaPlayer.Play();
}

// Method to stop media player
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mediaPlayer.Stop();
}
```